# Making Linux processes schedule based on other prcoesses

Tags: centos6, scheduling

I am using `CentOS release 6.7`.

I have 2 services, say `A` and `B`. Service `B` is dependent on service service `A`. For example, if service `A` stops, I want service `B` to stop automatically. Similarly, if service `A` starts, I want service `B` to also start automatically after that. (Service A can be running on a remote server)

Is there a tool or any utility which can help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

The **[Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/)** tool and the [*service groups*](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-GROUPS) feature can do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks, it looks useful. I made a small addition to original problem. Services `A` and `B` can be running on different machines. I couldn't find that feature in [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/)  tool.

Comment: No, I don't have an option for remote servers...